# Is there way to select only id from parentReference

Tags: onedrive

Request
GET /drive/root/children?select=name,size,parentReference
returns, for parentReference, for example,

"parentReference:{
"driveId":"3e2dd398785a81d",
"id":"3E2DD398785A81D!103",
"path":"/drive/root:"
}

Is there way that parentReference in reponse contains only id:
"parentReference:{
"id":"3E2DD398785A81D!103",
}

Answer (score 0):

Ideally you should be able to `?select=name,size,parentReference/id` but that currently doesn't work (it'll behave like `?select=name,size,parentReference`). We aim to fix that at some point though, and so you're more than welcome to use the former syntax and it should start working when we fix it. Until then you'll just get back some extra things you don't actually care about.